# Highstocks line.gapsize option not functioning properly

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am working with highchartjs  and i am using highstockjs and i am trying to use the following setting to create line breaks

```
plotOptions.line.gapSize: 720 // for setting a break in the line for points that are more than 12mins away.
```

I have created a jsfiddle[1]

The problem with the following dataset is 
1. Its not getting taking the interval properly
2. When using navigator and we cross date boundry it connects the breaks again.

[1] https://jsfiddle.net/wzvt279n/1/

Comment: From [gapSize docs](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series%3Cline%3E.gapSize) A gap size of 5 means that if the distance between two points is greater than five times that of the two closest points, the graph will be broken. The distance between your points is not constant and if you change the extremes, the distance can be bigger/smaller - at some points the distance will be not bigger than the closest point's range and the break will not appear. In your case, you should consider using [xAxis.breaks](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series%3Cline%3E.gapSize/xAxis.breaks)

Comment: I was under the impression that it applies to whole series and not just on the view in the navigator. But thanks @morganfree